# jhipster keycloak integration always redirect to localhost:8080

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak

`Angular/Spring` app generated using jhipster
here's my app configs "`application.yml`"

```
security:
oauth2:
    client:
        access-token-uri: http://test.com:9080/auth/realms/urms/protocol/openid-connect/token
        user-authorization-uri: http://test.com:9080/auth/realms/urms/protocol/openid-connect/auth
        client-id: urms
        client-secret: urms
        client-authentication-scheme: form
        scope: openid profile email
    resource:
        user-info-uri: http://test.com:9080/auth/realms/urms/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
        token-info-uri: http://example.com:9080/auth/realms/urms/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
        prefer-token-info: false
```

I deployed the application to my domain let's say "test.com" server.

**Problem**
Once user go to "`/login`" he will reach keycloak with redirection URL like

```
http://test.com:9080/auth/realms/urms/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=urms&redirect_uri=**http://localhost:8080**/login&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=F2xa8S
```

Any idea why it's fixed to `localhost:8080`?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my question. The issue was that I am running nginx to proxy to spring server. What I needed is that I should adjust my configuration to set the following header "HOST" so it will be

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header HOST $host;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Instead of simply using "proxy_pass" only

Comment: Thanks for reporting back with the fix.